# How to disable a widget when a button from a different class is pressed?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

Im making a `Button` which disables a `TopAppBar` menu form my user interface, the problem is that the `Button` is on one class an the `TopAppBar` in another, because one belongs to the screen and the other is shared between multiple screens.

code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen



Window.size = (300, 500)

navigation_helper = """


<UserScreen>

    name: 'user_screen'


    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        adaptive_height: True
        padding: (0, "80dp" , 0, 0)
    
    
            
            
                
        FloatLayout:
        
            MDRaisedButton:
                id: save_btn_user
                text: "Guardar"
                md_bg_color: "white"
                text_color: "black"
                font_size: 16.2
                pos_hint: {"left":1, "bottom": 1}
                size_hint: (.2,.2)  
                disabled: True   
                on_press: root.save_btn_press()
            
                               
                
            MDRaisedButton:
                id: edit_btn_user
                text: "Editar"
                md_bg_color: "white"
                text_color: "black"
                font_size: 16.2
                pos_hint: {"right":1, "bottom": 1}
                size_hint: (.2,.2)  
                disabled: False
            
                on_press:        
                    root.disable_top_bar()







<MainScreen>:
    name: "main_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
    
        MDTopAppBar:
            id: title_bar
            title: 'Dietas'
            md_bg_color: 0.08,0.07,0.45                     
            specific_text_color: 1,1,1
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
        
        Widget:


    MDNavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:
            id: scr
                    
            UserScreen:

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
    
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: '8dp'
           
                ScrollView:
                    MDList:

                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Usuario'
                            on_press: 
                                scr.current= 'user_screen'
                                title_bar.title = "Usuario"
                                nav_drawer.set_state('close')
                            IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch:
                                icon: 'account'
                                on_press: 
                                    scr.current= 'user_screen'
                                    title_bar.title = "Usuario"
                                    nav_drawer.set_state('close')
                            
                   
                            
                    
                            
MainScreen:
"""



    
class UserScreen(MDScreen):



    def disable_top_bar(self):
        self.a=MainScreen()
        self.a.disable_top_barr()
    

class MainScreen(MDScreen):
    def disable_top_barr(self):
    
        self.ids.title_bar.disabled = True
        print("testmsg")
    
class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = ("Dark")
        screen = Builder.load_string(navigation_helper)
        return screen
       
            


DemoApp().run()
```

As you may have seen, I tried creating two method, one in the `TopAppBar` class disabling it and printing a test message(that its shown) and the other in the `Button` class calling that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following approach

```py
    def disable_top_bar(self):
        self.a=MainScreen()
        self.a.disable_top_barr()
```

you will see no change in your GUI because each time you call that method, it will create a new instance of `MainScreen` (which is not related to your GUI) and call the asked method on it.

In order to access that specific instance you can use the method `get_running_app` of `MDApp` as follows,

```py
    def disable_top_bar(self):
        # First access the running app instance.
        app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        # Access the target screen that you set as the root widget.
        main_screen =  app.root
        # Call the method.
        main_screen.disable_top_barr()
```

As a note avoid using predefined names like `a`, `b`, `g` etc. when working with `KivyMD` widgets.